# Can Pandas DataFrame efficiently calculate PMI (Pointwise Mutual Information)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, entropy

I've looked around and surprisingly haven't found an easy use of framework or existing code for the calculation of Pointwise Mutual Information ([Wiki PMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_mutual_information)) despite libraries like Scikit-learn offering a metric for overall Mutual Information (by histogram). This is in the context of Python and Pandas!

My problem:

I have a DataFrame with a series of [x,y] examples in each row and wish to calculate a series of PMI values as per the formula (or a simpler one):

`PMI(x, y) = log( p(x,y) / p(x) * p(y) )`

So far my approach is:

```
def pmi_func(df, x, y):
    df['freq_x'] = df.groupby(x).transform('count')
    df['freq_y'] = df.groupby(y).transform('count')
    df['freq_x_y'] = df.groupby([x, y]).transform('count')
    df['pmi'] = np.log( df['freq_x_y'] / (df['freq_x'] * df['freq_y']) )
```

Would this give a valid and/or efficient computation?

Sample I/O:

```
x  y  PMI
0  0  0.176
0  0  0.176
0  1  0
```

Comment: Could you show your sample data and expected output maybe?

Comment: Hi, I've added a simple example, thanks for your help @JohnGalt

Comment: I think, you should be cacl'ing probabilities inplace of frequencies: `np.log( df['freq_x_y'] / (df['freq_x'] * df['freq_y']) )` should become `np.log( len(df.index) * df['freq_x_y'] / (df['freq_x'] * df['freq_y']) )`, by taking total records into account ?

Comment: Thanks that is definitely correct!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would add three bits.

```
def pmi(dff, x, y):
    df = dff.copy()
    df['f_x'] = df.groupby(x)[x].transform('count')
    df['f_y'] = df.groupby(y)[y].transform('count')
    df['f_xy'] = df.groupby([x, y])[x].transform('count')
    df['pmi'] = np.log(len(df.index) * df['f_xy'] / (df['f_x'] * df['f_y']) )
    return df
```

1. `df.groupby(x)[x].transform('count')` and `df.groupby(y)[y].transform('count')` should be used so that only
   count is retured.
2. `np.log(len(df.index) * df['f_xy'] / (df['f_x'] * df['f_y'])` probabilities to be used.
3. work on copy of dataframe, rather than modifying input dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Solution (with SKlearn KDE alternative as well):

Please comment for review

```
from sklearn.neighbors.kde import KernelDensity

# pmi function 
def pmi_func(df, x, y):
    freq_x = df.groupby(x).transform('count')
    freq_y = df.groupby(y).transform('count')
    freq_x_y = df.groupby([x, y]).transform('count')
    df['pmi'] = np.log( len(df.index) *  (freq_x_y / (freq_x * freq_y)) )

# pmi with kernel density estimation    
def kernel_pmi_func(df, x, y):
    # reshape data
    x = np.array(df[x])
    y = np.array(df[y])
    x_y = np.stack((x, y), axis=-1)

    # kernel density estimation
    kde_x = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=0.1).fit(x[:, np.newaxis])
    kde_y = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=0.1).fit(y[:, np.newaxis])
    kde_x_y = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=0.1).fit(x_y)

    # score
    p_x = pd.Series(np.exp(kde_x.score_samples(x[:, np.newaxis])))
    p_y = pd.Series(np.exp(kde_y.score_samples(y[:, np.newaxis])))
    p_x_y = pd.Series(np.exp(kde_x_y.score_samples(x_y)))   

    df['pmi'] = np.log( p_x_y / (p_x * p_y) )
```

Comment: Might also be good to choose `bandwidth` with cross validation. An example by Jake Vanderplas: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.13-kernel-density-estimation.html